# How do I enter data into this database?

Tags: java, android, xml, database, sqlite

This is an empty database for CRUD Android apps with Java, I want to enter the initial data in this SQLite without having to install the app first, so if they install the app then there will be initial data visible. How do I enter the initial data in this database?

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "contacts.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "CONTACTS";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 3;
    public static final String COLUMN_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_2 = "NMPENYAKIT";
    public static final String COLUMN_3 = "DESKRIPSI";
    public static final String COLUMN_4 = "GEJALA";
    public static final String COLUMN_5 = "SOLUSI";
    public static final String COLUMN_6 = "IMAGE";
    public static final String QUERY_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("
            +COLUMN_1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            +COLUMN_2+" TEXT, "
            +COLUMN_3+" TEXT, "
            +COLUMN_4+" TEXT, "
            +COLUMN_5+" TEXT, "
            +COLUMN_6+" TEXT)";
    public DataHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE);
        }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void insertData(ContentValues values){
        getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try running some insert statements on startup...

Comment: have you tried using that insertData method?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to insert data before the app is installed because the DB is based off the app context and its data is stored in its own local folder named after the app package.

Ideally you would want to insert the data on startup and have some way or noting that the data is installed such as checking if the DB is empty or saving it to shared preferences.

I would also recommend doing the insert operation during a splash screen if it is a lot of data and once its done you can load to UI to visualize the data.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to embed a pre-populated database and install it at first launch.

You just need to create your db file, containing the data you want to embed, and store it in the asset folder.

For example, using Room, you have to override the `RoomDatabase` object to create the DB from your file

```
@Database(entities = {Object.class, Thing.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "database.db";
    private static volatile AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static AppDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                            .createFromAsset("prepopulated.db")
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigrationOnDowngrade()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```